# PHP How to put the values of two arrays in one table?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays:

```
$aGente = array('jan'=> 'm', 'alice'=> 'v', 'veronica'=> 'v', 'herman'=> 'm',
'maria'=> 'v', 'angelica' => 'v' , 'nancy' => 'v', 'pieter' => 'm');

$aLeeftijd = array('jan'=> 12, 'alice'=> 17, 'veronica'=> 65, 'herman'=> 88,
'maria'=> 23, 'angelica' => 22 , 'nancy' => 45, 'pieter' => 39);
```

I need to put the names of all the people in a table and I need to seperate them so you have all the male people on the left and all the female people on the right side of the table. Can someone help me with this please?
See ya!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with left and right side? Sounds like you didn't normalize your database.

Comment: just check if values is `m` and add on the left, what's so difficult

Comment: I need to use a for each loop to do this but I don't know how.. Can someone explain?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { if ($value == "m") { ....... } }` explained..

Comment: Yeah i have that but how can i add them to a perfect table situation?

Comment: in the condition of `m` - add to the right, otherwise on the left. Do you mean table as database table?

Comment: No I mean a HTML table.

Comment: so `<tr><td>The content from the condition M</td><td>The other other condition content</td></tr>` ?

Comment: I would iterate through the 2 arrays and put the information in one multidimensional array where all `M` records are set into `$array[]['left']` and `$array[]['right']` then just foreach through this array and `<tr><td>$value['left']</td><td>$value['right']</td><tr/>`

Comment: Yeah but if the value == m how can i add them to the left side? Because if i want to add the names they all end up at the left side and it becomes one big list of names.

Comment: Ok i'm gonna try that! Thanks!

Comment: How did you get these results? Maye it is smart to change the code that give you these results.

Answer (score 1):

There might be more efficient way with built-in array functions, but to be honest I haven't researched right now.

The solution I can provide for easier access is to add the information in well structured new array which holds `left` and `right` side under the same key.

E.g. `$newArray[0] = array('left' => 'jan', 'right => 'veronika');`

Then `foreach ($newArray as $k => $v)` and you are able to set on the leftside of your table

```
<td>$v['left']</td>
```

and on the right:

```
<td>$v['right']</td>
```

And you will perfectly end up with table

```
jan | veronika
```

This is my work, which is not so quiality code, but gets the result:

```
<?php
function addToPeopleTable(array $genders, array $ages, array &$people, $where = 'left') {
    $g = $where == 'left' ? 'm' : 'v';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($genders as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $g) {
            $people[$i][$where] = array('gender' => $genders[$key], 'age' => $ages[$key], 'name' => $key);
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
$genders = array('jan'=> 'm', 'alice'=> 'v', 'veronica'=> 'v', 'herman'=> 'm',
'maria'=> 'v', 'angelica' => 'v' , 'nancy' => 'v', 'pieter' => 'm');

$ages = array('jan'=> 12, 'alice'=> 17, 'veronica'=> 65, 'herman'=> 88,
'maria'=> 23, 'angelica' => 22 , 'nancy' => 45, 'pieter' => 39);


$people = array();

addToPeopleTable($genders, $ages, $people, 'left');
addToPeopleTable($genders, $ages, $people, 'right');


?>
<table border=1>
<?php foreach ($people as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['left']['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['right']['name'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Output:

```
| jan      |    alice    |
| herman   |    veronica |
| pieter   |    maria    |
|          |    angelica |
|          |      nancy  |
```